# how can i make the sbt-release plugin automatically clean before doing the release?

Tags: sbt

I've tried a few approaches, such as `addCommandAlias("release", ";clean ;release")`, as well as something like:

```
ReleaseKeys.releaseProcess ~= {
   (seq: Seq[ReleaseStep]) =>
    cleanStep +: seq
}
```

where cleanStep is like:

```
lazy val cleanStep = ReleaseStep(
    action = st => Project.extract(st).runTask(clean, st)._1
)
```

and

```
lazy val cleanStep = ReleaseStep(
    action = st => Project.extract(st).runAggregated(clean, st)
)
```

Basically, none of these approaches work.  `runTask` works ok for a simple built.sbt build, but doesn't seem to work for a multi-module build.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working. I don't really understand what runAggregated is supposed to do; I would have thought it would do what this does. But anyhow this makes some intuitive sense; suggestions still appreciated since I feel like I'm missing something.

```
  lazy val cleanStep = ReleaseStep(
    action = st => {
      implicit val display = Project.showContextKey(st)
      val session = Project.session(st)
      val structure = Project.structure(st)
      (structure.allProjectRefs foldLeft st) {
        case (s: State, p: ProjectRef) =>
          Extracted(structure, session, p).runTask(clean, s)._1
      }
    }
  )
```